# cucumber wrap long scenario names

Tags: formatting, cucumber

People are creating long scenario name. Is there a way to wrap them for better readablity? Here's an example:

```
As an Auth User with migrated Service, when I navigate to Settings -> Your Info -> Discover More, I should see the Spectrum Mobile Spectial Offers and Updates card with a toggle button
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
As an Auth User with migrated Service, 
when I navigate to Settings -> Your Info -> Discover More, 
I should see the Spectrum Mobile Spectial Offers and Updates card with a toggle button
```

is there a way to do that?

Comment: Do you want to achieve that using code? And whatever you have written is that scenario name or steps?

Comment: that's the name - each step is a seprerate line.